# Matrix determinant simplification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Find the determinant of
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
> I_{N \times N} & Q_{N \times N} \\
> Q_{N \times N} & I_{N \times N} 
> \end{bmatrix},$$
> where
> $$Q=\begin{bmatrix} 
> q_1 & q_2 &  q_3 & \ldots & q_N\\
> q_{N+1} & q_1 & q_2 &\ldots & q_N-1\\
> q_{N+2} & q_{N+1} & q_1&\ldots & q_N-2\\
> \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots\\
> q_{2N-1} & q_{2N-2} & q_{N-3}&\ldots & q_1\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$.

We can use the following [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices):

$$ \det {\begin{pmatrix}X&Y\\Y&X\end{pmatrix}}=\det(X-Y)\det(X+Y)$$
$$\det {\begin{pmatrix}X&Y\\S&T\end{pmatrix}}=\det(T)\det \left(X-YT^{-1}S\right)$$
To show that

$$|A|=|I-Q||I+Q|=|I-Q^2|.$$
Now, I want to use the properties of the matrix $Q$ (look at repeated elements and the fact that the anti-diagonal transpose of $Q$ is equal to $Q$) to simplify the result and write $|A|$ in terms of $q_1,\ldots,q_{2N}$. Any idea how to continue from here?

Comment: So $Q$ is just an arbitrary $N \times N$ [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), right?

Comment: @darijgrinberg that is right. Yes.

Comment: Hmm. For $N = 3$, both $\det\left(I - Q\right)$ and $\det\left(I + Q\right)$ are irreducible polynomials in the $q_i$, so the furthest we can factor $\det A$ is as $\det\left(I - Q\right) \cdot \det\left(I + Q\right)$. This does not preclude some other formula that doesn't begin with a factorization, but it makes it somewhat unlikely.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks. What conditions make A singular? In other words, what does it mean when $det(I-Q)$ is zero?